# Converting a Char * to a float using sscanf

Tags: c, token

Im trying to convert a token to a float using sscanf. The code compiles and runs but whenever I enter a value I just get 0.0000. Its not converting properly for some reason.

Here's the code:

```
while(1)
        {
        printf("repl> ");
        char *storage [30];
        char *tok;
        char g;
        double my_double;

        char buffer[20];
        int pos = 0, i;
        fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);

        tok = strtok(buffer," ");



        while (tok != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(tok, "add") == 0) printf("YES!!");
        else if (strcmp(tok, "add\n") == 0) printf("YELZZ!!!");

        if (strcmp(tok, "quit") == 0) exit(1);
        else if (strcmp(tok, "quit\n") == 0) exit(1);


         if (sscanf(tok, "%f", my_double) > 0)
         {
             Push(NULL, my_double, &head);
         }
         else
            Push(strdup(tok), 0, &head);

        tok = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    Display(&head);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As variable `my_double` is of type `double` you will have to use `%lf` instead of `%f`. Also you missed `&` (as rightly pointed out by Chris)

```
if (sscanf(tok, "%lf", &my_double) > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try passing a pointer to the number into sscanf, rather than the number itself:

```
sscanf(tok, "%lf", &my_double);
```

The `sscanf` function needs to know where to store the result, so passing in a copy of my_double won't work.

Additionally, as pointed out by Abhay, you need to specify `"%lf%` as your format string if you're reading into a double.

Comment: Yea I tryed that, no dice

Comment: Confirm that tok contains the string that you think it does, **and nothing more**. Then Chris's code _will_ work.

Comment: Oh in fact tok might contain a "\n" but im not sure how to remove that and then convert @PhilPerry

Comment: Please give an example of your input?

Comment: Ex: repl> 3 2 or repl> 4   @cklin

Comment: Either way i put it im still getting the 0.000

Comment: `    void Push (char *Item, double num, node **head)
    {
        node *New = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (New == NULL) printf("Memory Cannot Be Allocated");
        New->valNum = num;
        New->valC = Item;
        //node *get_node(void*);
        //New = get_node(Item);
        New->next = *head;
        *head = New;
    }`

Comment: Is this the exact code you have?  I just stripped out references to `Push` and `Display`, applied Chris's correction, and it compiles and runs properly.